# Override some aspects of a TikZ style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Let's say I have created a `.sty`, which I eventually want to share with others, featuring the following:

```
\tikzset{
  photon/.style = {
    draw = black,
    decorate,
    decoration = {
      snake,
      amplitude = 1mm,
      segment length = 3mm
    }
  },
}
```

Here is the intended use in a `.tex` file:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[vertex] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of v1] (v2);
\draw[photon] (v1) -- (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the `segment length` and the `amplitude` is hard-coded. What would be the best way to let my users change those

1. per line?
2. per `tikzpicture`?
3. globally?

I naively tried to add

```
\tikzset{
    photon/.append style={decoration=segment length=1mm}
}
```

at the beginning of the `.tex` file but it is not working: I get `Missing number, treated as zero` and `TeX capacity exceeded`. I have the feeling that it is because this replaces the entire decoration with `segment length=1mm`.

In any case, this would only address my points 3 and 2 (by putting `tikzset` inside a `tikzpicture`).

Comment: `\tikzset` gives a global setting; You can override it locally by passing it to the `tikzpicture` as options. Each line can have options that are yet again different from the settings. The user can override your setting naturally at each step, as long as you give the name of your setting. (I.e. when you rename `amplitude`, the user naturally has to know about that.)

Comment: use the `.store in` handler. Also check out how `decorations` library deal with parameters.

Comment: You are missing a set of braces `photon/.append style={decoration={segment length=1mm}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a set of braces `photon/.append style={decoration={segment length=1mm}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,positioning}

\tikzset{
  vertex/.style = {
    % ???
  },
  photon/.style = {
    draw = black,
    decorate,
    decoration = {
      snake,
      amplitude = 1mm,
      segment length = 3mm
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[vertex] (v1);
  \coordinate[vertex, right=of v1] (v2);
  \draw[photon] (v1) -- (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  photon/.append style={decoration={segment length=1mm}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[vertex] (v1);
  \coordinate[vertex, right=of v1] (v2);
  \draw[photon] (v1) -- (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]